# How to add new array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I add a new array to a user session or same/existing session. I have the following two PHP files.

1. fruits.php

   ```
   <?php
   <form action="processfruits.php" method="POST">

   <select name="myfruit_list[]">
       <option value="apples">Apples</option>
       <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
   </select>

   <select name="myfruit_list[]">
       <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
       <option value="pears">Pears</option>
   </select>

   <input type="submit" value="Confirm Order">

   </form> 
   ?>
   ```
2. processfruits.php

   ```
   <?php

   $data = array();
   $data = $_POST['myfruit_list'];

   echo "Number of Fruit Bowls: " . count($data) . "<br />"; 

   foreach($data as $selection => $name)
    {   
      echo "<br>" . $selection . ":     ";
      $string = implode(", ", $name);
      echo $string . "<br />";   
    }  

   ?>
   ```

The output I wish to achieve for each processing/confirmation under same user session:

```
   Number of Fruit Bowls: 4

   Data 1:   Apples, Grapes 
   Data 2:   Oranges, Pears 
   Data 3:   Apples, Pears  
   Data 4:   Oranges, Grapes
```

How can I get the array to look like the one above each time the user submits the Confirm Order button without overriding the first order confirmation or array.

Comment: Your first php file should throw you tons of errors.

Comment: `fruits.php` is not PHP. It's HTML between PHP tags which will fail spectacularly should you run it with error reporting enabled.

Comment: Sorry the first file is a HTML file with a php extension. Main reason is that I  have to use session_start() and another include file (php) before the HTML tags. I wasn't thinking straight.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {
    $_SESSION["data"]=array_merge($_POST['myfruit_list'],$_SESSION["data"]);
    $data = array();
    $data = $_SESSION["data"];
    $t=2;
    echo "Number of Fruit Bowls: " . count($data)/2 . "<br />";

    foreach($data as $selection => $name) {   
        if($t%2==0) {
            echo "<br>";
            echo "data : ".($t/2)." ";
        }
        else { 
            echo ",";
        }

        echo $name;
        $t++;
    }
}
else {
    $_SESSION["data"]=[];
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"> 
    <select name="myfruit_list[]">
        <option value="apples">Apples</option>
        <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    </select>
    <select name="myfruit_list[]">
        <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
        <option value="pears">Pears</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Order">
</form>
```

updated as requested......

```
    <?php
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {


   if(isset($_POST["del"]))
   {    
    $oft=$_POST["del"];
   unset($_SESSION["data"][2*$oft-1]);
    unset($_SESSION["data"][(2*$oft-2)]);

    }
    else
   {

    $_SESSION["data"]=array_merge($_POST['myfruit_list'],$_SESSION["data"]);

    }

    $t=2;
   $data=$_SESSION["data"];
   echo "Number of Fruit Bowls: " . count($data)/2 . "<br />";

    foreach($data as $selection => $name) {   
    if($t%2==0) {
        echo "<br>";
        echo "data : ".($t/2)." ";
    }
    else { 
        echo ",";
    }

    echo $name;
    $t++;


    }
    }

   else {
$_SESSION["data"]=[];
     }
   ?>

      <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"> 
<select name="myfruit_list[]">
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
</select>
<select name="myfruit_list[]">
    <option value="grapes">Grapes</option>
    <option value="pears">Pears</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Confirm Order">
      </form> 


   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST"> 
   <input type="text"  placeholder="row number to be deleted..." name="del">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete row">
   </form>
```

ok..one more form..add this code to the same page...

```
    <form action="add.php" method="POST"> 
     <input type="submit" value="add"/>
     </form>
```

**add.php**........

```
   <?php

    session_start();

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
    {
     $conn=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("could not connect to database");
     $db=@mysql_select_db("stack",$conn) or die("could not select database");

      $data=$_SESSION["data"];
     $temp="";$t=0;

    foreach($data as $selection => $name) {  


    if($t%2==0) {
     $temp=$name;
    echo $temp;
     }
    else { 

    $id=rand(1000,9999);
    $row=ceil(($t/2));
    $sql="insert into st(id,row,fruit1,fruit2) values(\"$id\",\"$row\",\"$name\",\"$temp\")";
    $res=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die("could not execute ");


       }    
       $t++;
    }

    }
     ?>
```

Comment: To take the process up the next level, how can I remove an array of fruits if an user wishes to remove a particular pair of fruits from the array?

Comment: Thanks Archit, I will try out the updated answer and let you know.

Comment: Archit, you are brilliant. Many thanks my friend. The updated answer is fantastic.

Comment: Can I please request for a last help, how can I load/insert the array in its current format into a mysql database. Do I encode to a json string first? The database table is a simple one with just four fields, 1. ID, 2. row number, 3. fruit1, 4. fruit2.

Comment: Archit, I will try that and get back to you. Thanks so much.

Comment: Archit, wish I could upvote you now and accept your answer as the best but I have not enough reputation points as I have just started on stack. You're help so far has been brilliant. The add.php file worked like a charm. My background is VBA programming and I will starting helping others to earn some rep points. Thank you for all your help and inspiration.